# Mockery fails with 'Could not load mock ... class already exists' when running with --code-coverage

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, code-coverage, php-7.0

I am trying to mock a class for phpunit. Php unit fails with the error `Could not load mock ... class already exists`. This is the only test I'm running, so it can't be the case that the class is mocked already.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is the error case:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class DeactivateACSTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testDeactivateAcs()
    {
        $deviceController = \Mockery::mock('overload:App\Http\Controllers\Cloud\DeviceController');
        $deviceController
            ->shouldReceive('deactivateACS')
            ->andReturn('hilfehilfehilfe');

        $devCon = new \App\Http\Controllers\Cloud\DeviceController();
        $this->assertEquals('hilfehilfehilfe', $devCon->deactivateACS());
    }
}
```

When running it without `--code-coverage` it works:

```
[13:10:15] vagrant@homestead [~/Code/ekp] $ phpunit --filter DeactivateACS
PHPUnit 6.5.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


 ==> Tests\Feature\DeactivateACSTest              ✓

Time: 1.08 seconds, Memory: 16.00MB

OK (1 test, 3 assertions)
```

However, when running it with `--code-coverage` it fails:

```
[13:10:23] vagrant@homestead [~/Code/ekp] $ phpunit --coverage-html coverage --coverage-text=code_coverage.txt --filter DeactivateACSTest
PHPUnit 6.5.10 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.


  ==> Tests\Feature\DeactivateACSTest              ⚈

Time: 5.79 seconds, Memory: 44.00MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\DeactivateACSTest::testDeactivateAcs
Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock \App\Http\Controllers\Cloud\DeviceController, class already exists

/home/vagrant/Code/ekp/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Container.php:220
/home/vagrant/Code/ekp/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery.php:116
/home/vagrant/Code/ekp/tests/Feature/DeactivateACSTest.php:11

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

Comment: the same problem
how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 54):

You should add these annotations before the functions that are mocking this class.

```
/**
 * @runInSeparateProcess
 * @preserveGlobalState disabled
 */
```

For reference you can check out the phpunit documentation.

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.runInSeparateProcess

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.preserveGlobalState

Comment: Does not work in phpunit 7.4.3 and Mockery 1.2.2. It still gives the ``Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock Service, class already exists`` error.

Comment: Great trick! This worked perfectly with PHPUnit 9.5 and Mockery 1.4 for a test class where I was using several instance mocks with the `overload` prefix. Ultimately I ended up using the `@runTestsInSeparateProcesses` annotation on the whole class for simplicity. (In my case `@preserveGlobalState` wasn't actually needed... YMMV).

Comment: Update... turns out that that particular test class could run without `@preserveGlobalState disabled`, but I had to add it to the class comment to get the whole test suite to run properly.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and fixed like this:

1. There was another test in my unit tests (not mockery test) which had `require_once` on the PHP file that had the class I was mocking. I've removed that line.
2. I've added `processIsolation="true"` in test suite