# Why Mockery is unable to make an alias of my model

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, laravel-5.7, mockery

I have the following model:

```
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    public static function foo():bool
    {
      return true;
    }
}
```

And for that I made the following controller:

```
namespace App\Controler;

use App\Model\Foo;

class MyController
{
   public function bar()
   {
      $value=MyModel::foo();
      if($value){
        return "OK"; 
      }
      throw new \Exception("Foo not true");
   }
}
```

And I want to test my controller:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use App\Model\MyModel;
use Mockery;

class MyControllerTest extends BaseTestCase
{
   public function testBar()
   {
      $mock=Mockery::mock('alias:'.MyModel::class);
      $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn(false);
      /// Rest of thest here
   }
}
```

But once I run my test I get the following error:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.20 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

E                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 1.62 seconds, Memory: 14.00 MB

There was 1 error:

1) Tests\MyControllerTest::testBar
Mockery\Exception\RuntimeException: Could not load mock App\Model\MyModel, class already exists

/var/www/html/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery/Container.php:226
/var/www/html/vendor/mockery/mockery/library/Mockery.php:118
/var/www/html/tests/MyControllerTest.php:20

ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.
```

In order to mitigarte the error as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53266979/4706711 I tried:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use App\Model\MyModel;
use Mockery;

class MyControllerTest extends BaseTestCase
{

  /**
   * @runInSeparateProcess 
   * @preserveGlobalState disabled
   */
   public function testBar()
   {
      $mock=Mockery::mock('alias:'.MyModel::class);
      $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn(false);
      /// Rest of thest here
   }
}
```

But still I get the same error.

Based upon the answer of @mohammad.kaab I tried the following:

```
namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;
use App\Model\MyModel;
use Mockery;

class MyControllerTest extends BaseTestCase
{

  /**
   * @runInSeparateProcess 
   * @preserveGlobalState disabled
   */
   public function testBar()
   {
      $this->app->instance(MyModel::class, \Mockery::mock(MyModel::class, function($mock){
            $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn(true);
        }));
        $myModel = $this->app->make(MyModel::class);
        dd($myModel::foo()); // should return true
   }
}
```

Thout it can't work because The `\Mockery::mock` mock an instance and does not mock the class itself. Therefore I tried the following:

```
   public function testBar()
   {
      $mock=Mockery::mock('alias:'.MyModel::class);
      $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn(false);
      /// Rest of thest here
   }
```

And did not worked for me.

Comment: `$mock=Mockery->mock(` this part does not look like a valid syntax to me. You either create an instance of the mock or you call a static method? You are also missing a semicolon in the imports.

Comment: I fixed it tyhe typo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mockery fails with 'Could not load mock ... class already exists' when running with --code-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51708289/mockery-fails-with-could-not-load-mock-class-already-exists-when-running-w)

Comment: No I as you can see I tried the  and did not worked for me.

Comment: What about that semicolon when importing `use Mockery` is this missing only here in the question?

Comment: Still I get the error with the semicolymn as well.

Comment: Bold opinion with how mocking and the container works with Laravel, dont use static methods. What is the reason for that method to be static in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this code

```
$this->app->instance(MyModel::class, \Mockery::mock(MyModel::class, function($mock){
            $mock->shouldReceive('foo')->andReturn(true);
        }));
        $myModel = $this->app->make(MyModel::class);
        dd($myModel::foo()); // should return true
```

Comment: It does not work for the following reasons: 1. I need an alias and using the aliased approach still does not work. I get the very same error. Also I need to mock a STATIC method I do not want to make an instance of it.